# Publishing private app on Google Admin Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-workspace

I've tried to publish a private app on Admin console. We've created an organization group and selected only one e-mail address there (mine, actually).

We followed Option 1 here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en#zippy=%2Cmanaging-private-apps-in-admin-console-versus-google-play-console%2Cedit-the-title-or-apk-of-a-private-app%2Cedit-advanced-private-app-details

Now our app says "Approved" on the Admin Console, but how can I find it? It's supposed to show up on the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

Actually private apps uses `Closed testing tracks` to distribute the app. so you can find the links to your app from closed testing tracks

[image: screen]